# Combine complete URL and virtual URL, like a browser does

Tags: c#, uri, relative-path

I have a complete URL like: `A: http://www.domain.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee.ext`.

I have a relative URL like: `B: ../../fff.ext`

I’m looking for the easiest way in .NET C# to combine these two URLs and get:
`C:  http://www.domain.com/aaa/bbb/fff.ext`

This is like what browsers does: you’re browsing URL A, then, page’s HTML have an hyperlink as B, the resulting URL is C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd probably have better luck looking up "PathCanonicalize".

Also, with my findings, one of the overloaded [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91.aspx) constructors can handle this:

```
Uri combined = new Uri(
  new Uri("http://www.domain.com/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee.ext", UriKind.Absolute),
  "../../fff.ext"
);
```

[Proof is in the pudding](http://www.ideone.com/qgYHa)